# MySQL extract substring using regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex

My SQL request:

```
SELECT Path FROM Media m join Article_Image am on m.id=am.mediaid where am.articleid=609;
```

The value in the Path column:

```
/uploads/dddef9788caab36fcfd0ce05c84373e3.jpeg
```

I need to extract `dddef9788caab36fcfd0ce05c84373e3` using regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have any native regex extraction support.  But we can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` instead:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PATH, '/', -1), '.', 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: I need to wait 8 minutes